# Could a medieval trebuchet and parachute work to deliver a soldier past a 20-30 foot wall?

Tags: science-based, warfare

**This is a ludicrous question and isn't meant to be serious. I had an idea of catapulting people with parachutes and thought it would be funny. This was inspired by [Elemtilas answering a previous question I had](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/141723/62335).**

Could a trebuchet deliver a person with a parachute past a 20-30 foot high wall (alive and mostly uninjured)? The person just needs to clear the wall by any distance, although closer would be better.

If there are catapult designs that act better than a trebuchet, feel free to use that instead.

**Note: the previous version of the question was something dumb(er) about parachutes.**

Comment: I personally doubt that a medieval parachute would be able to properly deploy within 10 meters of the ground. You might as well parachute the soldiers into a pit of spikes and see what happens.

Comment: Trebuchets were used to send corpse during siege, so weapon choice is good

Comment: The exact definition of parachute may be a bit maleable @Shadowzee, plus, who said there weren't either spies (who make maps of what's over the wall) or Tokubetsu Kōgekitai - equivalent soldiers.

Comment: God help the poor "volunteer" who has to undergo those g-forces.  Don't think you'd be remembering to deploy a parachute, and those forces might even kill you.

Comment: @StephenG G-forces can surely be mitigated by making something more of a carnival ride out of the trebuchet. Without modern engineering a primary counterweight to produce the first rotation within a secondary weight(s) to achieve 'escape' velocity. To the parachute: http://www.rocketshoppe.com/info/The_Mathematics_of_Parachutes.pdf
Trebuchet and other implements of ballistic delivery didn't occur out of nowhere, and sieges being difficult and expensive things one can't help but imagine that people tried to find ways to do what the OP asks.

Comment: Well, perhaps a series of trebuchets instead, mechanically much simpler and the math doesn't need to be known in detail by the engineers to produce a timed system. Imagine a train track running through the legs of a series of trebuchet, a manned glider is locked onto a wheeled trolley, the trebuchet radii/weights are set & aligned such that they accelerate the trolley in sequence along a track which is given elevation towards the walls. The pilot releases the locking bar to the trolley as the last 'gear' is hit and launches into the sky.

Comment: with a properly designed system (angled/curved contacts) even, it wouldn't need to be timed to any peculiar degree, say 1/2 a second, tho necessarily the more 'off' the timed contact is the more jarring the contact. (stuff like 'but medieval pplz didn't know x y or z' hardly work out, being as pursuing such ridiculous projects is how people learn such things in the first place)

Comment: @GiuPiete, Rather than post lengthy comments, you should answer the question....

Comment: How about an almost vertical trajectory implement, designed to have the apex of the trajectory on top of the wall, so that there's very little downward velocity at the point of landing on top of the wall (yes i know that's not fully over, but it would be inside the castle outer wall) Not sure what kinda of implement could do that though ¬_¬

Answer (score 9):

**Can you launch a nuclear weapon horizontally?  Sure!  Why would you want to?**

- A [counterweight trebuchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet#Chinese_trebuchets) can easily clear a 10m wall.
- Silk existed during medieval times, so a parachute could be made.
- Altimeters did not exist during medieval times and could not, so your <s>victim</s> <s>volunteer</s> *conscript* needs another solution to tell him when to pull the string.

What solutions exist?

1. He could pull the release just as he crests the wall.  As @StephenG points out, there's a lot of forces at play (g-forces, tumbling through the air, wetting your pants...).  But, someone with unusual fortitude and presence of mind could, conceivably, do it.
2. The release could be tied off to the trebuchet or any nearby tree such that it would (a) yank the <s>conscript</s> intrepid hero around and then pull the release.  Assuming neither whiplash nor a broken neck occurs, it's likely more predictable and the <s>urine</s> *Jarate* becomes an added benefit to the attack.
3. If you really want points for style, though, drag a grappling hook tied in the middle of a length of rope that lets it grab onto the wall as our intrepid hero passes over, thereby releasing the parachute and leaving the embedded hook with rope dangling *outside* the wall for the rest of the <s>canon fodder</s> infantry.
4. And if you *really* want points for style, tie the warlord's flag to our intrepid hero's ankles.  It would not only clearly announce the castle/town's imminent change in loyalty, but would act in a loose way like rocket fins, straightening our hero's flight out at the expense of height and distance.  Yes, it would also make him a blooming target, but we're looking for *style,* right?

*And there are thousands of ways to solve the problem of infiltration that are better than this.  But they definitely lack style.*

*P.S. Had Terry Pratchett (Discworld) lived long enough, I firmly believe he would have used this idea to get dwarves into troll fortifications.  It's definitely* his *style of solution.  The 202<sup>nd</sup> airlifted division, the "Screaming Beetles" having the motto, "Rendezvous with Gold!"*

Comment: May I ask where the nuclear weapon is comming from?

Comment: @DarthDonut, the reference is a quote from the movie, *The Hunt for Red October.*  It's being used as a metaphor for futility.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me! I have seen that amazing movie only in German, and I fear they either did not translate it accordingly, or I just can't remember.

Comment: I'd upvote for the Terry Pratchett idea, but the rest is good too. :-)

Comment: @DarthDonut, the scene is when Ryan and Skip are researching what the doors on the front of Red October could be.  After the question about ICBMs, Skip realizes they could be a "caterpillar drive."

Comment: Actually I'd bet that the best tactic would be deploying the parachute from the start. As **Loren Pechtel** mentions, the world record for lowest parachute jump is 29 meters with an already deployed parachute. Given that medieval-tech parachutes must be at best equal and reasonably worse than modern parachutes, and that a good deal of the braking should be done over the horizontal vector of the speed if the soldier does not want to splash against a wall, I think that a 45º angle with an already deployed parachute would grant a nice badminton ball effect.

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly, the answer is almost a yes.  The world record for the lowest parachute jump is only 29 meters, although this obviously involved an already deployed parachute in some fashion (I only found the record, not how it was performed.)  This would be problematic but not utterly impossible for your trebuchet jumper.  Since your jumper would have a horizontal velocity he's going to need a bit more distance but I don't know how much more.

There was another answer who thinks he won't survive the launch but I disagree--since a trebuchet works by a counterweight rather than a spring there's simply a high acceleration, not a huge spike as the spring releases.  You can lower the force by increasing the size, if it's big enough the jumper survives.

However, I don't think medieval technology could build a parachute anything like as good as a modern one.  How much worse I don't know.

Now, if you want to make it even lower I could imagine a cold-gas rocket assisted deployment.  I have a hard time picturing that being even remotely reliable with medieval tech, though.

Note, also, that it's going to be a very dangerous jump no matter what.  The jumper will not have any control over their landing spot or time to prepare for a less than ideal landing and most things they might be landing on will be pretty hard.

Comment: The parachute might not be an issue. http://www.angelfire.com/electronic/awakening101/davinci-chute.html Leonardo da Vinci designed one and a replica worked fine.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight  - Of course the fictional medieval designer of the fictional parachute might not be as competent as da Vinci.